# Parsing an array containing a single object in Node JS

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

I have an object like that

```
[{"created_at":"Thu Aug 15 11:45:05 +0000 2013","id":367975226434670592,"id_str":"367975226434670592","text":"What makes @asana the 'Tesla of productivity tools': http:\/\/t.co\/TFzHFEpXqJ"}]
```

And I am interested only in 'text' part in this object.

I tried

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log( obj.text );
```

but It didn't work, help ?

Comment: What does `console.log( obj );` show you?

Comment: @Harry console.log( obj.text ) shows me undefined

Comment: Ok, thats like expected, but what does `console.log( obj );` show you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are parsing an array containing your object as its only element. 
Try obj[0].text.

Comment: jepp thats what I expected.